# OpenERP 7.0 Database Restore in Windows

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am very new to OpenERP & PostgreSQL.

I have newly installed OpenERP 7.0 on Windows Machine, and I have a database file from old OpenERP 7.0 and PostgreSQL server (Windows Platform)

To restore old server database, Do I need to restore that database from Web Interface? or Do I need to import database in PostgreSQL only?

When I tried to restore the database file from web interface it says "RESTORE DATABASE - Could not restore the database"

Please see the attached file.

I will appreciate your advises to help me restore my database from old server to new server.

Thanks & regards

[ScreenShot - Importing PostgreSQL database File from Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP2s8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

### Openerp Restore Database

### In Web Interface

1. Choose your db backup file correctly.
2. Type the Master Password of your Openerp Server, If wrong, It will show "Could not restore Database!".
3. Type New Database name : your database name must not same existing database.

In case, Some openerp server show Alert like that you have seen.

But actual is it is working backend. So if you seen alert, please go to the http://localhost:8069/web/database/selector and find your new database name.

If you found your new restore database name, your database restore is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pgAdmin to backup and restore Openerp database. I prefer using this than openerp backup function